# APNS service sending 200 for expired device token?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am testing Apple Push Notification service (sandbox mode) before integrating in my app. We will potentially be sending out Push Notifications in the order of thousands per minute - so one of the major requirement is to not send notifications to an Invalid(deleted) device token if an app is deleted (or re-installed).

The device token, received in:

```
application(_ application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
```

in App Installation specific. A new installation creates a new token and the previous one becomes invalid.

As per [Apple's APNS document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns), sending a request for an expired device token should return:

> 410 The device token is no longer active for the topic.

However, I am consistently getting 200 for both valid and expired device tokens. The notifications for correct device token are delivered to the device whereas the ones for Invalid (expired) tokens are not.

I am using, [npm apn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn) package on the server side and testing on a device running iOS 12.3.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Any solution? I am receiving multi notifications per device if I need to switch to http2.

Comment: @Raunak Did you Find any solution ?
even I am using **npm apn** and
 expecting 410 but not getting it

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this too. I usually get a 200 response code and the following body for an invalid/expired token:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 7942205170696355362,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

I assume you will have to parse the response body and check the success or failure count to determine whether the notification actually delivered.
If you get a failure, then remove token this from your DB(or wherever you store your tokens to send to) so that it doesn't attempt to send it to the same token again.

Comment: How do you get this response from http2 request to apns, I only get "apns-id: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" response